# Error installing avogadro with CMake 'lconvert: could not exec No such file or directory'

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cmake

I'm brand new in ubuntu. I'm trying to install Avogadro. The program need the following packages, which I could install: 
CMake - OpenBabel 2.3.2 - Qt4 - Git - Eigen2. 
Here it is the recepy to install the :

```
cd $HOME/src
git clone git://github.com/cryos/avogadro.git
mkdir -p $HOME/build/avogadro
cd $HOME/build/avogadro
cmake $HOME/src/avogadro
make -j2
sudo make install
```

It was unable to compile, but when I skipped the 'git clone' step it seemed to work just fine. After several stops during the CMake compiling process (software actualizations, get Doxygen, get flex, get bison) I was able to compile.
But when I introduce the 'make -j2' command the installation stops as follows:

```
Orr22@javi-87:~/build_avogadro$ make -j2
[  0%] Built target elementcolor
[  0%] Built target bsdyengine
[  2%] Built target spglib
[  3%] Built target navigatetool
[  4%] Built target tubegen
[  4%] Generating libavogadro_hu.qm
[  6%] Built target OpenQube
[  6%] Generating moc_animation.cxx
lconvert: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lconvert': No such file or     directory
make[2]: *** [libavogadro/src/libavogadro_hu.qm] Error 1
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
make[1]: *** [libavogadro/src/CMakeFiles/avogadro.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions to proceed?

Thanks in advance,

Orr22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install package `qttools5-dev-tools`

Explanation:

The errror message `could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lconvert': No such file or directory' is telling you that an executable named lconvert is not there.

To find out which package has the missing file use `apt-file search lconvert`

Comment: Found the package needed! Successful install